# View more than 1000 files in HDFS directory with NFS Gateway mount

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, nfs

I've mounted an HDFS directory to my local Windows system using Hadoop's NFS Gateway service (configured via Cloudera 5.4). The mount works fine, but when I access the data through Windows Explorer (or navigating there via command line), it only lists out 1000 files in the directory.

The directory actually has about 20k files in HDFS. What can I do to make all the files in this directory accessible via my NFS mount?

Comment: That's interesting. Is mounting from Unix has the same effect? It might be Windows limitation I think..

Comment: @Ruslan Tried mounting from an Ubuntu server and it lists all 100% of the files as expected. Seems you might be right with the Windows limitation idea. Any ideas on things I could modify on the Windows side to resolve this?